# Parsing units and amounts from text in swift

Tags: swift

I was wondering what the best approach would be to separate multiple items from a string in swift. I'm hoping to separate a unit and an amount from a string and then use those values to create an object of my ingredient class.

For example:

```
var string = "4 cups sugar"
```

I would need to grab the 4 (amount) and convert it to an int and then grab the unit (cups)

```
var amount = 4  
var unit = "cups"
```

Another example:

```
"3 large eggs"
```

In this case I would want to pull out the 3 (amount) and the unit would be empty.

```
var amount = 3
var unit = ""
```

Then I would create my object using the unit and amount values.

I'm still a novice at swift, and more-so with string manipulation so I'm not entirely sure how to approach this, any help in the right direction would be great.

I am working with an ingredient class that is structured as:

```
class IngredientModel {  
var amount = 0
var unit = ""

init(amount : Int, unit : String) {
    self.amount = amount
    self.unit = unit
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want the `amount` to be an `Int`. Hard to deal with 2/3 cups and the like.

Comment: Thank you for that tip, slipped past me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **SWIFT** you can do this early with optionals & generics. I can show you how? with your example..

Your **Ingredient** class

```
class IngredientModel {

   var amount = 0
   var unit = ""
   let units = ["cups","spoon"] //Add your required units

   init(string: String) {

     let array = string.components(separatedBy: " ")
     if let _amount = array.ref(0) {
        self.amount = Int(_amount) ?? 0
     }

     if let _unit = array.ref(1),
        units.contains(_unit){
        self.unit = _unit
     }
   }

}
```

An **Array Extension** to prevent index out of range

```
extension Array {
  func ref(_ i:Int) -> Element? {
     return 0 <= i && i < count ? self[i] : nil
  }
}
```

[image: Playground screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for. Could you explain how the extension works? I'm new to that functionality.

Comment: @KrisValas Please read the chapter on [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151) in the Swift book.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410120-components) right, you should use the `components(separatedBy)` function. The parameter should be one space in quotes like so:

`let array = yourString.components(separatedBy: " ")`